# Is it fine to keep changing from AHCI to RAID constantly?

Tags: 20.04, bios, sata

So, I had windows 10 for a while now and I decided to install Ubuntu in dual boot, however as you may know I need to switch to AHCI to use Ubuntu, I know that you could setup Windows to use AHCI, However I want to keep using RAID. Will changing from AHCI to RAID constantly have any damage to either software or hardware of the laptop.

Comment: It shouldn't break anything, but why keep using RAID ? How many disks do you have ?

Comment: Only one I'm planing on adding another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There's no benefit in using that "RAID" with more than one disk and absolutely no benefit if using only one.**

Even if you intend to use some sort of RAID later on, the "RAID" from your motherboard's drive modes ISN'T something you'd want to use. So, yes, install AHCI support in Windows and be done with changing modes. But, as said in comments, doing what you're doing won't break anything, it's just annoying and purposeless.